# Unable to send email with boto3 pinpoint send_messages - need example

Tags: email, boto3

I have a validated domain, and sending a direct email via the AWS Pinpoint console works fine. However, I can't get the same to work with Boto3 send_messages.

I get `{'DeliveryStatus': 'PERMANENT_FAILURE', 'StatusCode': 400, 'StatusMessage': 'Request must include message email message.'}`

But I have a `MessageConfiguration` Default Message with a simple string for Body, and I've tried `BodyOverride` as well. No problems sending SMS.

I've been unable to snag an example of `send_messages`, and I think if I saw a working example of an email send, that'd be all I need.

Snippet:

```
response = ppClient.send_messages(
    ApplicationId=pinpointId,
    MessageRequest={
        'Addresses': {
            'mguard@{validateddomain}.com': {
             # 'BodyOverride': 'Hello from Pinpoint!',
            'ChannelType': 'EMAIL',
            }
        },
        'MessageConfiguration': {
            'DefaultMessage': {
                'Body': 'Default Message for EMAIL.',
                'Substitutions': {}
             }
         }
    }
)
```

Comment: Did you get a solution to this?